# Why am I getting notification of my own flag?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, flagging

Why am I getting notification of my own flag and can't even review it.

Is it some new feature? I never noticed it previously. Refer screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Good question.....

Comment: I had a similar problem today with tag wiki edits. When I created them I was receiving notifications about edit suggestions to review, but my queue was empty.

Comment: The review system has been siginifcantly revised since this question was asked. So is this still an actual problem?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson never had that problem again

Comment: never had that either.